# When i save or publish a post setting reset wp

Tags: publish

When I publish an article this resets several settings:

- my generatepress theme logo setting
- new ads created with wp quads
- and the newsletter form reset

I disabled the maximum extension, and I have the impression that it is a bug with the database, if anyone has a lead to help me find the solution I would be delighted, thank you in advance

Comment: You'll have to ask the respective Theme and plugin developers.